# How to join 2 maps with values together by a key?

Tags: java, join

I have two files that I've read into 2 HashMaps.  The object these files represents have 5 fields to be filled.  Each map provides three.  I need to join these by the overlapping third object.

Here is the code I have so far.  It seems to work, but I'm trying to learn if there is a neater way to do this.

(If relevant: these files ARE different sizes.  Also, it's coming in as a csv, so to fill in the map, I'm simply splitting on "," and building the object.

Let's say MyObj holds five Strings, ill call them s1 - s5.
In the files, s3 is what we join by.  In the final, I want to look up by s1.

```
String company = "CompanyA";

HashMap<String, MyObj> first = readFromFirstFile(); //fills s1-s3
HashMap<String, MyObj> second = readFromSecondFile(); //fills s3-s5 
HashMap<String, MyObj> joined = new HashMap<>();

first.forEach((key,val) -> {
MyObj obj = second.get(key);

    if (obj != null && val.s5.equalsIgnoreCase(company)) {
      MyObj obj = new MyObj(s1,s2,s3,s4,s5);
      joined.put(obj.s1,obj);
    }
});
```

Example:

```
Example data file1:
1000 -> CompanyA, 0000001
1001 -> CompanyA, 0000002
1002 -> CompanyA, 0000003

Example data file 2:
0000001 -> "Snickers Delivery 11/29/2017", "Hershey"
0000002 -> "Potato Chips Delivery 11/20/2017", "Lays"
0000003 -> "Returned Shipment Video Games 11/20/2017", "EA"

Goal Data:
1000 -> CompanyA, 0000001, "Snickers Delivery 11/29/2017", "Hershey"
1001 -> CompanyA, 0000002, "Potato Chips Delivery 11/20/2017", "Lays"
1002 -> CompanyA, 0000003, "Returned Shipment Video Games 11/20/2017", "EA"
```

Comment: Doesn't this code ignore entries in the second map that don't have the same keys as the first map?

Comment: Why use `HashMaps` for first and second variables?

Comment: @KarlNicholas Yes, second file may contain lots of stuff I can ignore.

Comment: @SedrickJefferson Because I am looking them up below by a key I thought they makes more sense. If another data type makes sense, please share.

Comment: Can you provde an example of the two hash map contents? Is there any reason you can't use putAll(Map<? extends K,? extends V> m) to join the two hashmaps?

Comment: @Juan Example added. Can that 'fill in the data' so to speak?

Comment: 'val.s5==company'  <-- can't compare strings this way.

Comment: In a HashMap you have 1 key and 1 value, can you restructure your example making clear which is the key and which tthe value? the comma separated list lets to think there are move than one values...

Comment: @Juan in the examples the first element (Before ->) is the key.  The first two hashmaps do not have to exist in memory as they are, the goal is to simply get to the final hashmap.

Comment: The final hashmap you are making reference to is not a hashmap, it can't have 3 values for a key. In any case if you want to use a hashmap for a structure like this one it should be a HashMap<String,List<String>>. But you should evaluate if that is what you really want.

Comment: @Juan The data I'm showing is the `MyObj` that holds multiple String.  I'm simply illustrating key -> {values that are in Object}

Comment: I got it now. I hadn't payed atention to HashMap definition. From the lookup perspective I think HashMap is the best alternative. The only thing I see redundant is val.s5.equalsIgnoreCase(company), I would think that searching by the key should be enough.